# sqlite join query iPad

Tags: ios, sql, swift, sqlite

I have three tables

```
Personal_video
+------------------------------+ 
 |presonal_video_id | title | 
  ----------------------------
       1            |  test1| 
       2            |  test2| 
       3            |  test3| 
       4            |  test4| 

personal_video_tags
+------------------------------+ 
     |tag_id |       tag_title | 
  ----------------------------
       1            |  august| 
       2            |  2016  | 
       3            |  2015  | 
       4            |  2014  | 


personal_video_tag_mapping
+------------------------------+ 
     |tag_id |       presonal_video_id | 
  ----------------------------
       1            |  1  | 
       2            |  2  | 
       3            |  3  | 
       4            |  1  |
```

Now i want to write a query which will return me the videos on the basis of common tags like if user select tag "August" & "2014" then the query should return videos which is connected to both the tags.

currently my query is

```
 SELECT presonal_video_id,title 
 FROM personal_video 
 WHERE presonal_video_id IN 
 (
    SELECT personal_video_id AS PID 
    FROM personal_video_tag_mapping 
    WHERE tag_id IN ("1","2")  AND privacy_level != 2   
    GROUP BY personal_video_id 
    HAVING COUNT( PID ) > 1 
 )
```

It is giving me write result but when there is large data then it takes long time. Can someone teel me correct way to write this query

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.presonal_video_id, t1.title 
FROM personal_video AS t1
JOIN personal_video_tag_mapping AS t2 
    ON t1.presonal_video_id = t2.presonal_video_id
JOIN personal_video_tags AS t3
    ON t2.tag_id = t3.tag_id    
WHERE t3.tag_title IN ('august', '2014')
GROUP BY t1.presonal_video_id, t1.title 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thank's for the reply , this query is working fine but unfortunately it is showing me less results , means my query giving me 33 results but your query giving me 7 results. I am trying to fix the issue

Comment: Hay Giorgos I change COUNT(*) = 2  to COUNT(*) > 1 and now it is working fine. Thank You for your help